# How do i write a code which can calculate the cross product of two vectors?

Tags: matlab

How do i write a code which can calculate the cross production of two vector ? Both of these two  vectors are 1 by 5 vector
At first, i write the code like

```
a=randn(1,5);
b=randn(1,5); 
cross_c=cross(a,b)
```

or

```
a=randn(1,5);
b=randn(1,5);
cross_c=cross(a,b,5)
```

But the window always show me

```
A and B must be of length 3 in the
dimension in which the cross
product is taken.
```

How do i write a code which can calculate the cross production of these two  1 by 5 vectors?

My matlab version is 2015b

Comment: One of the first line of documentation for `cross` is: _If A and B are vectors, then they must have a length of 3._ => your vectors with 5 components will never satisfy the input of this function.

Answer (score 2):

The cross product of two vectors a and b is defined only in three-dimensional space and is denoted by a × b.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: Note (to OP) that it's possible in MATLAB to take the cross product of two `3-by-n` matrices. However, MATLAB will treat each column as a separate vector with length 3, so even though it appears you may have larger dimensions in MATLAB, you really can't. It's still vectors in the three-dimensional vector, as it says in this answer.